# How to add items to welcome menu with javascript

Tags: 2013, jquery, menu

I need to add new menu items to the welcome menu in SP 2013 using javascript/jquery. How can this be done?

Additions to #welcomeMenuBox dont work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the `ServerMenu` - it's the source for the rendering of the welcomeMenuBox.

try something like this:

```
var newItem = document.createElement('ie:menuitem')
newItem.setAttribute('type', 'option')
newItem.setAttribute('onmenuclick', 'STSNavigate2(event, "https://google.de")')
newItem.setAttribute('text', 'Google')
newItem.setAttribute('description', 'open google and have fun')
newItem.setAttribute('menugroupid', '100')
document.querySelector('#welcomeMenuBox menu[type="ServerMenu"]').append(newItem)
```

and the result will be

[image]

if you set the `menugroupid` to something other than `100` the result will look like:

[image]